# two or multiple-row touch jQuery carousel

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, slider, carousel

Is there any solution?

description: 
I'm trying to use [touchcarousel](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/touchcarousel/), but there is only combine 2 items in 1 solition in it carousel. It isn't suitable, because I use 'each loop', where I can't paste 2 item in 1. It seems to me I need to find carousel with API ability integration.

I thought, I got it - [jQuery RS Carousel](http://www.richardscarrott.co.uk/assets/javascript/jquery/ui-carousel/demo/), but I there are 2 reason why I can't use it. 
-it looks cheap
-multiple rows API don't work correctly.